# How do I change font size inside VBA next to a .Value?

Tags: excel, vba

I wanna change the font size from where I start formatting as hours: `Format(Sheet3.Range("F" & TaskRow).Value`...
I tried using `.Font.Size = 8` on the front, back and inside the code but can't get it to make it work. I am very new to VBA, sorry if this is a stupid question, really tried looking for an answer online.

```vb
TaskText = Sheet3.Range("C" & TaskRow).Value & _
  vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "De " & Format(Sheet3.Range("F" & TaskRow).Value, "h:mm AM/PM") & " a " & _
  Format(Sheet3.Range("G" & TaskRow).Value, "h:mm AM/PM") & _
  vbCrLf & Format(Sheet3.Range("D" & TaskRow).Value, "###-###-####")
```

Comment: And where is `TaskText` displayed?

Comment: You cannot format the appearance of different parts of a cell using just the `.Value` - You need to use the `Characters` collection after setting the value. - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56739498/excel-vba-applying-bold-format-to-certain-characters-in-a-word-doc-table-cell-no

Comment: @GSerg inside an object (square) that you can drag around, the texts stays inside of it. It is an schedule program, it shows the name, from what hour it starts and when it ends, and at the end it gives you the phone number of your client. I wanna give it a size 8 font to the hours and phone number, while keeping the name at size 11

Comment: Eg: `myShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(6, 4).Font.Size = 8` where 6 is the position to start the formatting, and 4 is the number of characters to format.